# Can I get chapter metadata for protected files

Tags: ios, drm, mpmediaitem, avasset

Right now, I'm using MNavChapters to get the chapter metadata for audio files and using MPMediaPlayerController to play the audio files.

This works great until I try to load an Audible (AA) book's chapters. The MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL returns nil because this is a "protected" file. Is there an alternative to read the chapter metadata?

Current non-working code:

```
NSURL *assetURL = [self.mpmediaitem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]; //this is null :(
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
MNAVChapterReader *reader = [MNAVChapterReader new];
NSArray *chapters = [reader chaptersFromAsset:asset];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that this works in iOS 9

Comment: assetURL is always nil for DRM-protected audiobooks when I try this on iOS 9.2. Are you really sure this works in iOS 9?

Comment: Yes. Surprisingly, it works for Audible DRM books. (I think it worked for iTunes books too.) You can check out the app if you don't believe me. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/undulib-audiobook-audio-drama/id1024718755?mt=8

Comment: I still don't believe you :) I tried your app with two audiobooks I bought from iTunes Store. I can see individual chapters of these books in iBooks, but when I touch the chapter button in your app, no menu pops open. I wrote a new question (linked to this one), but got no reply yet.

Comment: @Dirk You're right! I guess it's more subtle. I know for a fact that the chapters work for protected Audible files. But, sadly, it doesn't work for iTunes protected files.